# SQL Random DBConcurrencyException Errors- VB.Net

Tags: sql-server, database, vb.net

I have an application, and SQL Server that 6 users have access to. Occasionally they will get a `DBConcurrencyException` error. By occasionally I mean I get a copy of their error a few times a week at most - and usually not by the same user. I have determined that it is NOT because another user has also updated the same "record." I have a feeling it has something to do with the conversion of decimals? between the server and the users workstation. However, I can not replicate the error.

I have tried updating a record on the application at the same time as the server.  Whichever one finishes first, wins. But there is NO error. Because I cannot replicate this error, and don't know how to "force" an error, I can't come up with a reasoning or solution.

So 2 questions:

1. Is my thinking that the error is possibly due to data conversion plausible? If so, how do I test for and/or correct this issue?
2. Is there a way I can force or fake the exception so I can build a proper solution? I'd like to know exactly WHY the error is happening before I start trying to force updates into the server.

Not sure what code would be helpful here, but I am using `SqlDataAdapter.Update` to update the server with changes.

Build update query:

```
SQLcmd = New SqlCommand("
    UPDATE [ACL].data_Demog_BGL SET
       [Offline]  = @Offline
       ,[ID_BGL_Assay]  = @Assay
       ,[Barcode_Number]  = @BarNum
       ,[Result]  = @Result
       ,[Result_Type]  = @RType
       ,[ID_Test_Outcome]  = @TOutcome
       ,[CLIR_Request]  = @CReq
       ,[CLIR_Entry]  = @CEntry
       ,[Tasklist]  = @Tasklist
       ,[Sequence]  = @Seq
       ,[CLIR_Date]  = @CDate
    WHERE ID_Demog_BGL = @ID
    ", Vars.sqlConnACL)

With SQLcmd.Parameters
        .Add("@Offline", SqlDbType.Bit, 0, "Offline")
        .Add("@Assay", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "ID_BGL_Assay")
        .Add("@BarNum", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255, "Barcode_Number")
        .Add("@Result", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255, "Result")
        .Add("@RType", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255, "Result_Type")
        .Add("@TOutcome", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "ID_Test_Outcome")
        .Add("@CReq", SqlDbType.Bit, 0, "CLIR_Request")
        .Add("@CEntry", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255, "CLIR_Entry")
        .Add("@Tasklist", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255, "Tasklist")
        .Add("@Seq", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255, "Sequence")
        .Add("@CDate", SqlDbType.Date, 0, "CLIR_Date")
        .Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "ID_Demog_BGL")
End With

da_BGLAssay.UpdateCommand = SQLcmd
```

and...

```
Me.Validate()
bsBGL.EndEdit()
da_BGLAssay.Update(dt_BGLAssay)
da_BGLAssay.Fill(dt_BGLAssay)
```

Comment: The code posted won't throw a DBConcurrencyException, it'll just overwrite whatever is in the DB with whatever the user put in the table? Update commands that throw concurrency errors at least do rowversion comparisons or have long complicated where clauses that compare current db values with old datatable values

Comment: @CaiusJard  I'm not sure if you're asking a question, but yes... and no.  Like I said, it's a very random error.  When I try to replicate the issue, get a DBConcurrencyException, I can't get it to throw the error.  Therefor I cannot determine WHAT is causing the error.  I had read on another site/forum that it can be caused by decimals not correctly rounding between the server and the users PC.  This causes the DB to think there's been an update, when there really hasn't been.

Comment: But it's not the DB that throws the exception. The exception is thrown by some intelligence on the .NET side of things issuing an UPDATE command with ExecuteNonQuery() and checking that the return value is less than the expected (e.g. expected 1, actual number of records updated 0. Throw). For that there would need to be something kooky in the UPDATE; right now the only time it will throw is if the record has been deleted and there is no record with ID x

Comment: @CaiusJard  I tested your statement and it was correct.  I loaded a record into the application, deleted the record in the DB, clicked update and got the DBConcurrencyException.  But the question now is; how is this record getting "deleted" if no one is deleting it.  The only other thing I can think of is; for some reason the "ID" variable is not getting set correctly so it's looking for the wrong record... I will have to test this now that I have an idea of what I'm dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has a few options for tracking changes to tables, and some techniques for finding out who deleted data - problem is that most apps these days roll their own user system and everyone/webserver uses a common login so that might not help much...

If you're fortunate enough to have multiple db users you might be set already: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3090/how-to-find-user-who-ran-drop-or-delete-statements-on-your-sql-server-objects/ or https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4269/how-to-find-out-who-deleted-some-data-sql-server

If you rolled your own user system then you might need to roll out something to do some logging. Could certainly be programmatic and minimal effort but what sort of effort would depend on how your data layer is implemented

You could also put a trigger to log the time and what data is deleted - if these records are disappearing when the office is closed, perhaps some automated job .. If you have a table of login and logout times (relatively trivial) it can help determine the person

---

Handling the DBConcurrencyExcpetion is also possible: when you catch it, in your case you know the record has been deleted. Just offer to reinstate it and if the user says yes, change the RowState from Modified to Added and save it again, to use the INSERT rather than the UPDATE query

Note that if you're just doing `Update(datatable)` then the adapter could be UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE hundreds of rows and you might not know which one caused the exception. You can go row by row in a loop

---

Oh, which just made me think of something else; are you aware that even though a dataapter/tableadapter method for saving changes in a datatable is called `Update()` that it will call INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE according to whether the RowState is Added/Modified/Deleted? I ask because some people think that `Update()` only does updated, but if your datatable has some deleted rows, when you call `Update` those rows will be removed from the DB

`Update()` would have been better off called `SaveChanges`.. but yes, just incase you didn't know - it could be a cause of your deletes, if stray records in your DT are marked as deleted and you `Update()` intending to save changes to a modified row